# gSoap not sending more than 4 bytes of response

Tags: c++, linux, rest, gsoap

I have the following code for sending the response, but only the first 4 bytes are sent in response. Why the behaviours is like this?

```
int sendRaw(struct soap *soap, const char *respMsg)
{          
        if (soap_response(&objSoap, SOAP_FILE)) /* OK HTTP response header */
        { 
                soap_end_send(&objSoap);
                return soap->error;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(respMsg); i++)
        {
                if(soap_send_raw(&objSoap,&respMsg[i],1))
                {
                        return soap_end_send(&objSoap);
                }    
        }
        soap_end_send(&objSoap);
        return SOAP_OK;
}
```

and my calling is like this

```
  const char  msg = "this is a rest response";      
  return sendRaw(&objSoap,msg);
```

Comment: Just to add ive implemented the http get method for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `respMsg` is a `char *`, it's size equates that of any other pointer in your system, which given your problem description appears to be 4 bytes (32 bits):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(respMsg); i++)
```

If `respMsg` is a string, then use `strlen(respMsg)` [this is the case in your little example], if it is some kind of binary data, then you will need to pass along the actual size.

Comment: ok This seems to overcome the problem but now im getting the response 500 at my client from which im send the request. Although the response from my server is 200.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(respMsg)
```

This is 4, because your pointer is 32bit, which is 4 bytes.

You want

```
strlen(respMsg)
```